# How to upload file from postman to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I've been reading a lot of post and articles and still have no idea why my request fails. There is a asp net core 3.1 app. Simple controller code :

```
[Route("api/v1/user")]
public class BlobController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("uploadphoto")]
    public async Task<UploadPhotoResponse> UploadPhoto([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

Postman request :

[image]

Headers :

[image]

Every time i'm getting **400 bad request** result and can't get inside **UploadPhoto** method.

Comment: 400 bad request means client-side error,and I checked your settings,and tried with your cades with your settings in postman ,but get no error. Have you used any custom middleware ?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng actually yes. I use Zscaler. maybe its a problem

Comment: You could try without your custom middleware or make a break point in your custom middleware and observe what will happen when you debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `IFormFile` to `UploadPhotoRequest` --> multipart file

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace UploadPhoto.Controllers
{

    public class UploadPhotoRequest
    {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/v1/user")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {


        [HttpPost("uploadphoto")]
        public string UploadPhoto([FromForm] UploadPhotoRequest file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
            return file.Name;

        }
    }
}
```

#### Postman Collection to verify

```json
{"auth":null,"event":null,"info":{"_postman_id":null,"description":null,"name":"test.http","schema":"https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json","version":null},"item":[{"description":null,"event":null,"id":null,"name":"1","protocolProfileBehavior":null,"request":{"auth":null,"body":{"disabled":null,"file":null,"formdata":[{"contentType":"application/json","description":null,"disabled":null,"key":"image","type":"file","value":"settings.json","src":null},{"contentType":null,"description":null,"disabled":null,"key":"name","type":"text","value":"ram","src":null}],"graphql":null,"mode":"formdata","options":null,"raw":null,"urlencoded":null},"certificate":null,"description":"1","header":null,"method":"POST","proxy":null,"url":"https://localhost:5001/api/v1/user/uploadphoto"},"response":null,"variable":null,"auth":null,"item":null}],"protocolProfileBehavior":null,"variable":null}
```

There are two ways to upload files.

1. Uploading via single file
2. Uploading via multipart

> This option is used, if there are multiple files/fields to upload

## To upload single file, In postman

1. Switch to body tab
2. select binary
3. select File
   [image: Single Binary]

## To Upload multipart file, In postman

1. Switch to body tab
2. select form-data
3. add keys

> if it is a file, hover to the right section of key. you will see option to change it to file.

[image: Multipart]

### Alternative solution

[Dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code) is similar tool with great control over these.

## For Single file

```
POST https://req.dothttp.dev
// select as a binary
fileinput('C:\Users\john\documents\photo.jpg') // path to file
```

## For Multipart upload

```
POST https://req.dothttp.dev
// selects as multipart 
multipart(
    'name'< 'john',
    'photo'< 'C:\Users\john\documents\photo.jpg',
// and many more
)
```

Comment: I've tried both approaches. One of them exactly on my screen above. Maybe controller code incorrect?

Comment: can you share `UploadPhotoResponse` code and response?

Comment: why? I can't even get inside `UploadPhoto` method.

Comment: Can you check latest edit, it seems issue is not with postman, but with current code. 
if you are using multipart request. definate structure has to be known to asp, otherwise it will respond with the Unprocessible entity or bad request.

Comment: Did you try this solution on localhost? I did and still failed.

Comment: Hey I uploaded complete example of controller and postman collection as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244870/discussion-between-prasanth-and-).

Answer (score 0):

As odd as it may sound but make sure to use "file" as parameter name in your controller, eg

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckContent(IFormFile file)
```

Only way I could post from Postman to a MVC controller
And remember to disable your antiforgery methods